# Converting raster (TIFF) to .grc format in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, raster-conversion

I want to convert a raster (TIFF) to .GRC format in ArcGIS but I cannot find the conversion tool to do it.

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: what does .grc came from ? I mean what software does it use ?

Comment: There's an old [blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/imagery/grd-and-grc-files-now-supported-in-arcgis-10-1/) that claims *read* support, but I didn't see anything that claims *write* support.  The [master matrix of supported formats](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm) doesn't list .grc at all.

Comment: You can use GDAL to perform the conversion.  GDAL has support for GRC format. https://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Vince:

> There's an old
>   [blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/imagery/grd-and-grc-files-now-supported-in-arcgis-10-1/)
>   that claims *read* support, but I didn't see anything that claims
>   *write* support.  The [master matrix of supported formats](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm)
>   doesn't list .grc at all.

The title of that old blog is .[GRD and .GRC files now supported in ArcGIS 10.1](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/imagery/grd-and-grc-files-now-supported-in-arcgis-10-1/) and starts by saying:

> With the upcoming release of ArcGIS 10.1 there is now support for the
>   reading of .GRD (Grid) and .GRC  (Classified Grid) raster files that
>   are produced by MapInfo, Vertical Mapper and various telecom wireless
>   planning tools.